# Bringing a converted user-shared mailbox to an Office 365 cloud shared mailbox

Tags: powershell, office365

We use AD Connect to sync to O365. Within O365, we converted a user's mailbox to a shared mailbox, however, that mailbox is still connected to the user in AD. We need to detach the user with the shared mailbox and bring the shared mailbox completely in the cloud into O365.

We are trying to to do this the best way possible. The first idea is to delete the user and restore as a O365 shared mailbox.

```
Get-MsolUser -ReturnDeletedUsers | Restore-MsolUser
```

Delete user, then restore to O365 shared mailbox vs it being a converted mailbox in a hybrid environment.

Comment: What happens if you run `Disable-RemoteMailbox` on that account in on-prem Exchange and let it sync to O365?

Comment: Hmm, we will have to try it out. By the way, I love your user name. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can Disable the mailbox.

```
Disable-Mailbox <MailboxIdentity>
```

When you disable a mailbox, all Exchange attributes are removed from the associated user account in Active Directory. The disconnected mailbox is permanently deleted based on the MailboxRetention property value for the mailbox database (the default value is 30 days).

refer here for more information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients/disconnected-mailboxes/disable-or-delete-mailboxes?view=exchserver-2019

Answer (score 0):

if you want to permanently delete the mailbox.

```
Remove-Mailbox -Identity <Identity> -Permanent $true
```

See here:

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients/disconnected-mailboxes/permanently-delete-mailboxes?view=exchserver-2019#use-the-exchange-management-shell-to-permanently-delete-an-active-mailbox[enter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients/disconnected-mailboxes/permanently-delete-mailboxes?view=exchserver-2019#use-the-exchange-management-shell-to-permanently-delete-an-active-mailbox%5Benter) link description here][1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients/disconnected-mailboxes/permanently-delete-mailboxes?view=exchserver-2019#use-the-exchange-management-shell-to-permanently-delete-an-active-mailbox)